# Location returns null value sometimes

Tags: android

```
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(super.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(super.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(super.getActivity(), new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
    } else {
        Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

            LogUtils.v(TAG, "Latitude : " + latitude);
            LogUtils.v(TAG, "Longitude : " + longitude);
        }
    }
```

Sometimes I get the value, but then I do not know what happens that gives me null.

Comment: Because there is no location to give, lastKnownLocation does not have to give you a valid location

Comment: mmmm I do not understand the answer well, but I have the GPS active and nevertheless still gives me null

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It is not clear why you find the `null` confusing. If a location is not available, it's not available - you should write your app to deal with that.

Comment: You're requesting a location from the network provider, not GPS.

Comment: @TKK then what would be the solution

Comment: The other answers and comments are correct that the last known location may sometimes be null regardless. I was just pointing out that you were talking about GPS but your code is using a different provider.

Answer (score 0):

Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current) says that `Location` can be null in these cases:

- Location is turned off in the device settings. The result could be
  null even if the last location was previously retrieved because
  disabling location also clears the cache.
- The device never recorded    its location, which could be the case of
  a new device or a device    that has been restored to factory
  settings.
- Google Play services on the device has restarted, and there is no
  active Fused Location Provider client that has requested location
  after the services restarted. To avoid this situation you can create
  a new client and request location updates yourself.